# Package manager error, cant install new packages

Tags: linux, debian, linux-mint

When trying to install any package i get the following error, I am using linux mint

```
sudo apt-get install gtk-recordmydesktop

Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
The following extra packages will be installed:
  recordmydesktop
The following NEW packages will be installed
  gtk-recordmydesktop recordmydesktop
0 to upgrade, 2 to newly install, 0 to remove and 63 not to upgrade.
Need to get 0 B/179 kB of archives.
After this operation, 974 kB of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] y
Selecting previously unselected package recordmydesktop.
dpkg: warning: files list file for package 'less' missing; assuming package has no files currently installed
dpkg: warning: files list file for package 'gir1.2-panelapplet-4.0' missing; assuming package has no files currently installed
dpkg: warning: files list file for package 'libgail-3-0:amd64' missing; assuming package has no files currently installed
dpkg: warning: files list file for package 'git-flow' missing; assuming package has no files currently installed
dpkg: warning: files list file for package 'laptop-detect' missing; assuming package has no files currently installed
dpkg: unrecoverable fatal error, aborting:
 files list file for package `pepperflashplugin-nonfree' contains empty filename
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (2)
```

Answer (score 0):

Normally this error message will be prompted when if the file under /var/lib/dpkg/info/* is corrupted. regarding this rename the file example git-flow,less and run te below command and reinstall it again

```
apt-get remove git-flow --purge 
apt-get install git-flow
```

Hope this might fix your issue

Comment: sadly it doesnt help, when i try the first command i get exactly the same error message

Comment: looks as if there has been an update issue somewhere. Please try the following to see if it helps

sudo apt-get -f install
sudo apt-get autoremove
sudo apt-get purge
sudo apt-get clean

Comment: i tried all that but got the same error. i also get this error occasionally dpkg --configure -a'

Comment: If you didn't remove those files yourself, they may be symptoms of a more serious error. Is your hard drive dying? Either way, reinstalling your system, possibly on different hardware if something is failing, may ultimately be the only remedy.